# A function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that (i) $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge |x-y|$ , $\forall x,y \in \Bbb R$ and (ii) $f$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to construct a function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ (if it exists) such that

(i) $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge |x-y|$ , $\forall x,y \in \Bbb R$  and

(ii) $f$ is bounded.

My attempt:

The first thing that came up on my mind was a rapidly oscillating function. I tried to do it with some composition of $\sin$ and $\exp$ but it doesn't work for entire $\Bbb R$!

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Taking $y = 0$ in the first inequality gives that $|f(x) - f(0)| \geq x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $f$ must be unbounded.

Comment: $|f(n)-f(0)|\geq n$ and let $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty hopeless. For any $x \ge 0$,
$$
|f(x)-f(0)| \ge |x-0| = x \\
$$
and so
$$|f(x)| \ge x - |f(0)|
$$